# Какие есть тонкости организации загрузки больших файлов на php

Tags: php, fileupload

Какие есть тонкости организации загрузки больших файлов на php?

Comment: 1) Ограничение в `php.ini`. 2) Соединение может оборваться. 3) Хостер прибьёт процесс, который работает слишком долго.

Comment: а как можно обойти проблему обрыва соединения, как можно сделать возможность до качки.Может есть смысл заливать через FTP(php library) чем POST

Comment: Я бы вообще порезал файл на части и гнал каждую часть с контрольной суммой, требуя повторную передачу битой части.

Comment: каким образом можно разбить видео файл?

Comment: Как можно его порезать?